# How to make two divs overlap without knowing the absolution postion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I need two divs to look a bit like this:

```
    |               |
 ---|    DIV I      |------------------------
|   |_______________|                       |
|             DIV II                        |
```

This is an easy task if I know the absolute position, but my divs can be dragged with JQuery .draggable(), so the position is unknown.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Which div (or divs) can be dragged, and along what axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you position div I relatively within div II, you can draw it "outside" div II by using negative margin.  For example:

```
.divi {
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

If, however, divi can be dragged also, then you may have a bit of troubles making this work with pure css.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your logo to be above the content div, but both divs can be moved at any time, or one of them, have you tried using the logo divs z-index as something really high like z-index:9999; to make sure it always displays above the content div (this is if i'm understanding the question correctly of course).